# Fetch all parents and children with "connect by" query for a particular input in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have a table com_customer_mst, it contains customer_id and their parent_customer_id, i need to fetch all parents and children for a particular customer_id as input. one customer_id will have a single parent but could have multiple children.

i have run this query:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, customer_code, PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID FROM SBSA_AXIA.COM_CUSTOMER_MST
start with customer_id = 154
  connect by prior CUSTOMER_ID = PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID;
```

but its only giving all children.

```
customer_id     PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID
61              12
18              12
111             12
250             12
14              15
```

Comment: `start with ..connect by` fetches recursively - it doesn't sound like what you're looking for. You can compose two selects: 1. get the parent and 2. get all children. Then `union` the results.

Comment: how to get the parents ? above query worked to fetch children. There will be only one parent for one custmer_id.

Comment: `SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID FROM SBSA_AXIA.COM_CUSTOMER_MST WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 154`

Comment: all the parents including parents of parents, not a single parent.

Comment: Need to play with it a bit (which I can't unless you prepare [a fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/)) but it should have the same logic only reversed. Try `SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, customer_code, PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID FROM SBSA_AXIA.COM_CUSTOMER_MST
start with customer_id = 154
  connect by prior PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID;`

Comment: tried this also.. parent_customer_id is not unique like customer_id. so it will give:  ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data
01436. 00000 -  "CONNECT BY loop in user data"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: What do you mean "non unique" ? you said there's only one parent to a customer.

Comment: but two children may have a same parent right ? what would come in parent_id column, its not unique we can see.

Comment: But you're going from 154 up, this should be a single chain of customer-ids

Comment: 154 could be a parent for multiple customer_id's. which 154 parent to choose.. it will be confused.. u got it ? we only need our customer_id's chain.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a clear definition of what you're looking for. Start with that before you try to implement.